# OpenLayers 6 GeoTiff style expressions - why is band value between 0 and 1?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I have a Cloud Optimized Geotiff (COG) with some weather data that has only one band. The pixel values represent cloud height and are in the 0-70 range. In leaflet-georaster I can style this easily with a function, testing the actual pixel value:

```
function echotopColor(input) {
    const value = input[0];
    if (value === -1 || value === 0 || value === 255 || isNaN(value)) {
      return "rgba(0,0,0,0.0)";
    }
    if (value >= 70) return "rgba(0,0,0,0.0)";
    if (value >= 50) return "#A10002";
    if (value >= 45) return "#FF0000";
```

I've tried to emulate this in OpenLayers looking at some of the geotiff samples:

```
new TileLayer({
  source: source,
  style: {
    color: [
      'case',
      ['>=', ['band', 1], .20],
      [161, 0, 2],
      ['>=', ['band', 1], .16],
      [255, 0, 0],
      ['>=', ['band', 1], .15],
      [202, 98, 1],
      ['>=', ['band', 1], .14],
      [223, 224, 58],
      ['>=', ['band', 1], .13],
      [98, 192, 59],
      ['>=', ['band', 1], .12],
      [19, 161, 196],
      ['>=', ['band', 1], 0.1],
      [22, 97, 129],
      [0, 0, 0, 0.0]
    ],
  }
}),
```

I've had to use trial and error to try to figure out what range the pixel values are in, and what I have is a complete guess but it at least colors it similarly. The OL documents say the style "band" operator will return a value between 0 and 1. How does that map to my original values ? Is there a way I can test the actual pixel values ? It seems really overly complex or I just am not getting it. Can I use a function to style geotiff ?

Comment: With version 6.9.0 https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases you can specify `normalize: false` and use original values

Comment: Sounds promising. I upgraded to version 6.9.0 and added the normalize: false option to my GeoTIFF source. I didn't see any change whatsoever in my styling value ranges. Is there a way to debug/see the actual values somewhere ?

Comment: Also I haven't seen any examples using the "case" syntax I'm using so please let me know if I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?  Though you didn't post other parts of your code, your issue was similar to mine.  What I finally discovered was that I was entering the interpolation and normalize options in the sources options and not for the OL GeoTIFF source.  This post clued me in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73375257/openlayers-geotiff-layers-getdata-returns-uint8-when-source-is-float.  My single band GeoTIFF styled properly after that.