# Openlayers Geotiff layer's getData returns Uint8 when source is float

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to visualize a single band COG with OL and am loading the geotiff as:

```
const source = new ol.source.GeoTIFF({
    sources: [
      {
        normalize: false,
        // band 1 elevation
        url: 'http://localhost/eu_dem_v22_itnord4326_cog512.tif',
        min: 0,
        max: 4711.0,
      },
    ],
  });
```

I then try to give the elevation some simple style:

```
 const layer = new ol.layer.WebGLTile({
    style: {
      color: [
         // omitted for readability
      ],
    },
    source: source,
  });
```

but when I call the layer's getData method I always get an Uint8 array, which ranges between 0 and 255.

The geotiff's info using gdal/rio shows that the tiff is a float64.
What is the proper way to get the float value from the layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`normalize` is an option of the GeoTIFF, not of the sources

```
const source = new ol.source.GeoTIFF({
    normalize: false,
    sources: [
      {
        // band 1 elevation
        url: 'http://localhost/eu_dem_v22_itnord4326_cog512.tif',
        min: 0,
        max: 4711.0,
      },
    ],
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It's sad, but I could not see it.